# How do I pass an object's property by reference into a function and mutate it?

Tags: f#

How do I pass an object's property by reference into a function and mutate it?

Here's an example of what I would like to do:

```
let mutable myProperty = (uint8) 0
...
member x.MyProperty with get() =  myProperty
                    and  set(v) = myProperty <- v
```

I then want to update that property through a function call by reference:

```
let update(property:uint8 byref) =
    property <- (uint8) 99

update(&x.MyProperty) // Doesn't compile
```

> Error FS3236  Cannot take the address of the value returned from the
>   expression. Assign the returned value to a let-bound value before
>   taking the address.

I'm sure this error is obvious. Unfortunately, I'm still not sure how to resolve it. I did attempt to reference some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#passing-by-reference). However, I'm still stuck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible at all. A property is just syntactic sugar for a pair of methods and not a direct reference to a value. You'd need to use a public field to be able to work with the address.

Answer (score 2):

Probably only public fields would work:

```
type MyClass() =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable Prop : (uint8)

let myInstance = MyClass()
update &myInstance.Prop
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the getter and setter byref

```
type X() =
  let mutable p = 0
  member x.P with get() = &p and set(v: int byref) = p <- v

let update (p: int byref) = p <- 99

let x = X()

update &x.P
```

Comment: That changes the type of the property, though. (That may be perfectly fine, but it affects all other usages of the property as well.)